# How to add JS and CSS files to all FrontOfice content in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

What is the best way to add JS and CSS files to Prestashop 1.6? I want those files to be available on all the pages in FrontOffice.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to create a module and add them in hookHeader():

```
public function hookHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/stylesheet.css', 'all');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/css/script.js');
}
```

Comment: Hello, If we like to add certain css only when footer hook execute. Is that possible if cache is enabled.

Comment: Hi! Just put the same code in hookFooter() or hookDisplayFooter() (they are aliases). It will be executed always, doesn't matter if cache is enabled.